# Prevent new dropdown from opening when passing over different menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a mega menu on this site that I'm building.
To open the mega menu, you hover over the item you want

```
<nav id="primaryMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-learn"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-teach"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-draw"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-build"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <ul>
</nav>
<div class="mega-menu">
    <div class="cat-learn">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-teach">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-draw">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-build">
    </div>
</div>
```

With JQuery, I made this function that adds a class of active to the corresponding `<div>` inside the mega menu.

```
    function menuHover(item, Megadrop){
        $(item).hover(
            function(){
                setTimeout( function(){$(Megadrop).addClass('active')}, 500);   
            },
            function(){
                setTimeout( function(){$(Megadrop).removeClass('active')}, 200);
            }
        );
        $(Megadrop).hover(

            function(){$(this).addClass('active') },
            function(){$(this).removeClass('active')}
        );
    }
    menuHover('.menu-learn','.mega-menu .learn');
    menuHover('.menu-teach','.mega-menu .cat-teach');
    menuHover('.menu-draw','.mega-menu .cat-draw');
    menuHover('.menu-play','.mega-menu .cat-play');
```

The mega menu appears below the nav, full width of the screen. The problem is that if you move the mouse over another list nav item while going to a spot on the mega menu, you'll activate that mega menu along the way. How do I prevent a new mega menu from opening when "passing over" another nav item inbetween the original nav item and the mega menu?

Should i ditch **hover** for a **onMouse** event with javascript?

Comment: That's expected behaviour for a hover/mouseover. You'd have to use a click event to keep the mega menu open instead of using a hover.

Comment: Should I change JQuery's hover for OnmouseOver  and OnmouseOut events instead?

Comment: No..you'd have the same issue. Your code can't distinguish the users intentions. What if they wanted to actually choose another top level item? It can't tell where the user *intends* to go...it can only react to where they *are*...See?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to add a delay before opening the next item. So if the user stops on a specific menu item after x amount of milliseconds, then the menu will open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known case. There's a guy that tackled it, mimicking the Amazon mega menu.

It's really worth the peek:
https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim

More info at the article:
http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

Good luck!